# How to shift a sequence (hidden layer) to the left in Keras?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, theano, keras, convolution

**I have some code that seems to do the job, but it behaves differently than I would expect.**

I want to have a (non-trainable) layer as part of my deep learning model, that shifts a sequence of vectors (hidden layer) one step to the left. My framework is Keras2 with Theano backend.

To provide a minimal example, if the input to the layer is a 3-time-step sequence, with two hidden components

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 5]]
```

then the output of the layer should be shifted to the left (with zero padding):

```
[[2, 3],
 [4, 5],
 [0, 0]]
```

I figured a 1-D convolution would do the job, where I specify the weights appropriately. With a convolution size of 3, I would just set the kernel weights for the left and middle position to 0, and have diagonal weights for the right position (just copying 1st and 2nd dimension):

```
[[[ 0.,  0.],
  [ 0.,  0.]],
 [[ 0.,  0.],
  [ 0.,  0.]],
 [[ 1.,  0.],
  [ 0.,  1.]]]
```

However, if I do it like this, the vector gets shifted to the right, not to the left. A fully working example:

```
import keras
import numpy as np

dim, length = 2,3
input_mat = np.arange(dim*length).reshape(1,length,dim)
inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(length,dim))

shift_left_kernel = np.asarray([np.zeros((dim,dim)),np.zeros((dim,dim)), np.eye(dim)])
outp = keras.layers.Convolution1D(dim, length, padding='same', kernel_initializer='zeros', use_bias=False, trainable=False, weights=[shift_left_kernel])(inp)

model_network = keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=outp)
print(model_network.predict([input_mat]))
#[[[ 0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1.]
#  [ 2.  3.]]]
```

Instead, I need to use

```
shift_left_kernel = np.asarray([np.eye(dim), np.zeros((dim,dim)),np.zeros((dim,dim))])
```

which seems illogical to me (I expect it would shift to the right, not to the left).
Where is the crack in my logic?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have already solved this, but I agree that right-left is confusing. I think it goes down to a low-level implementation choice whether to reverse the convolution kernel or not. From the Tensorflow documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn/convolution

> Note that although these ops are called "convolution", they are strictly speaking "cross-correlation" since the filter is combined with an input window without reversing the filter. For details, see the properties of cross-correlation.